# sql query to find distinct entry according to start and end time

Tags: sql

```
visit
tid     pid    date 
112   45   12-03-12
124   12   13-04-03
112   32   12-03-12
421   14   14-01-31

place
pid   start  end     starttime   endtime
45    xyz    qwe     12:00:13   14:30:00
12    abc    yst     15:45:00   16:00:00
32    tyu    jkf     15:30:00   17:30:00
14    nyk    por     08:30:00   10:00:50
```

I am stumped with this thing. I know the bit and parts but I am not able to get it all together. I need the result as follows

```
tid    start  end
112    xyz    jfk
124    abc    yst
421    nyk    por
```

As shown I need to derive only a single instance of ticket on the same day. But I need the start and end places to be according to time. start should have earliest instance while end the latest according to the startime and endtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for.

```
create table visit ( tid varchar(16), pid varchar(16), date datetime );
insert into visit values
    (112, 45, '2012-03-12'),
    (124, 12, '2013-04-03'),
    (112, 32, '2013-03-12'),
    (421, 14, '2014-01-31');

create table place ( pid varchar(16), start varchar(16), end varchar(16), starttime datetime, endtime datetime );
insert into place values
    (45, 'xyz', 'qwe', '2012-03-12 12:00:13', '2012-03-12 14:30:00'),
    (12, 'abc', 'yst', '2013-04-03 15:45:00', '2013-04-13 16:00:00'),
    (32, 'tyu', 'jkf', '2012-03-12 15:30:00', '2012-03-12 17:30:00'),
    (14, 'nyk', 'por', '2014-01-31 08:30:00', '2014-01-31 10:00:50');

select v.tid,
       (select start from place where starttime = min(p.starttime)) as start,
       (select end from place where endtime = max(p.endtime)) as end
  from visit v
  join place p using (pid)
 group by v.tid;

+------+-------+------+
| tid  | start | end  |
+------+-------+------+
| 112  | xyz   | jkf  |
| 124  | abc   | yst  |
| 421  | nyk   | por  |
+------+-------+------+
```

Note #1: My repro uses MySQL, so feel free to comment / vote up another answer if standard SQL varies from what I'm seeing.

Note #2: You should probably use datetime (rather than just time) in your `place` table, to allow for overnight flights.

Answer (score 0):

I think an SQL query like this will return your desired result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT visit.tid, 
(
   SELECT TOP 1 start
   FROM place 
   WHERE pid = visit.pid
   ORDER BY starttime ASC
) as start,
(
   SELECT TOP 1 end
   FROM place
   WHERE pid = visit.pid
   ORDER BY endtime DESC
) as end
FROM visit
```